# How to import the methods of two different classes from the same python file in the Robot Framework?

Tags: python, robotframework

My python file di.py has two different classes in it. I need to import them and use them in a robot file.
Can you please guide me through this issue.
My Python File: di.py

```py
import time

class di:
    ROBOT_LIBRARY_SCOPE = 'TEST CASE'
    
    def init(self):
       print("*****Initialization Complete*****")

    def read(self):
        display = "Read Complete"
        return display
        print(display)


class Example:
    ROBOT_LIBRARY_SCOPE = 'TEST CASE'
    counter = time.gmtime()

    def county(self):
        print(self.counter)
        return self.counter

    def clear_counter(self):
        self.counter = 0
        print(self.counter)
```

How can I use the methods of the classes in a robot file. My robot file is like

```
    *** Settings ***
    Library     Test.di
    Library     Test.Example

    *** Test Cases ***
    Test Read
        [Documentation]  Reads the DI value
        [Tags]  DI Read
        init
        ${var}  read    
        ${var}  clear counter
```

I am getting import errors while debugging. Can you please help me out.
Thank you very much.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The library imports are not correct. When you have a Python file with multiple library classes, the library import pattern should look like:

```
Library    <PYTHON_FILE_NAME>.<CLASS_NAME>
```

Your imports do not follow it, it looks like you have the robot file name instead of the Python file name.

```
Library     Test.di
Library     Test.Example
```

If we apply the pattern the correct imports should look like this:

```
Library     di.di
Library     di.Example
```